# SFSafariViewController as subview

Tags: ios, swift, sfsafariviewcontroller

I would like to use the SFSafariViewController but still add a few buttons of my own below. I havn't found a way to do this.

I tried using

```
let svc = SFSafariViewController(URL: testURL)
self.containerView.addSubview(svc.view)
```

This results in a blank white screen.
Is there a way to accomplish this with SFSafariViewController or do I have to build my own "browser" with WKWebView?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SFSafariViewController is not too customisable by definition (of Apple), it's suppose to give the user a close UX/UI experience of the regular Safari App.

If you want to add your own buttons you'd be have to create your own subclass of UIViewController and add a WKWebView as a subview to it.